# Какого типа должно быть поле для присвоения ему разных наследников одного класса?

Tags: delphi, ооп, классы

Есть некий класс `TPlayer = class`, у которого есть `property game`. Какого типа должно быть поле `game`, что бы я мог присваивать ему разные типы классов, которые получаю наследованием, вот так:

```
type
  TBaseGame = class
  TGameA = class(TBaseGame)
  TGameB = class(TBaseGame)
  TGameC = class(TBaseGame)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очевидно, что раз все классы наследуются от `TBaseGame`, то и тип вашего `game` должен быть `TBaseGame`, если вы хотите присваивать ему этих наследников.

Comment: то есть game: TBaseGame; и если  у GameA будет своё свойство А, а у GameB своё свойство В,  то присвоив game := TGameB.Create; я получу в game свойство B?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Вам нужно будет делать приведение типа TBaseGame к какому-то конкретному и только потом вы сможете обращаться к свойству, которое есть только у GameA или GameB. Т.е. можно сделать `b := (game as TGameB).B`, но если вдруг вы присвоите game тип TGameA, а попытаетесь привести его к TGameB, то получите исключение, поэтому перед приведением типа нужно делать проверку `if game is TGameB then ...`.

Comment: читаю и не пойму как правильно привести тип

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Значит, вы не понимаете, что такое операторы `as` и `is` в Delphi. Попробуйте [почитать про них](http://parsers.info/2009/12/operatory-as-i-is-delphi/). Вот пример кода, применительно к вашей ситуации: https://pastebin.com/X8GB0q7G

Comment: Я понял что такое операторы as и is, Object as TButton позволяет обращаться к объекту как к кнопке, а is проверка является ли объект кнопкой, не пойму как это правильно записать

Comment: Я не пойму как мне потом в  коде функции TGameA обратится к свойствам TPlayerа одним из свойств которого является сам TGameA?  Допустим TPlayer.Name := 'Vasia'; Как мне в function TGameA.myFunc():Boolean; обратиться к Name?

Comment: Я мог бы наследовать от TPlayer->TBaseGame->TGameA, TPlayer->TBaseGame->TGameB, но мне нужно что бы одна часть создавалась при конекте игрока и уничтожалась при дисконекте, а вторая, сама игра, при входе и выходе из игры

Comment: У Object нет Owner?

Comment: такое приведение верно? ((Self.FGamePlatform as TGamePlatform).Player as TPlayer).Name

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Верно, но лучше такие цепочки приведений не писать. Если вдруг понадобится дебажить код, то будет очень неудобно и всё равно придётся рефакторить. Лучше сразу завести 2 локальные переменные соответствующих типов (TGamePlatform и TPlayer) и использовать их.